# Setbacks of having nested Object methods - Javascript

Tags: javascript, oop

I am performing multiple nested calls within an object's methods, but wondering if this implementation could have any setbacks as my app scales and more functions are added.

These methods mainly modify the object's properties, and these are called one after the other in the following fashion:

```
let Obj = {
  state: 'initial',
  counter: 0,
}

Obj.changeState = function() {
  this.state = 'final';
  this.count();
}

Obj.count = function() {
  this.counter += 1;
}

// Run code
Obj.changeState();
```

For instance, an alternative: Functions that modify an object that is in the global scope directly.

Comment: I think there are no setbacks. I guess you worry about memory usage and performance, since your functions are objects, which `Obj.count` is a reference to your function object, so even you shadow clone your Obj to many instances, there are only one `Obj.count` function object instance. They should work fine without setback.

Comment: Thank you for the reply Eric. I was taking a look at the memory impact as the methods are called, and the GC is fast enough to prevent any issues.